# Detecting Windows or Linux?

Tags: java, linux, windows, platform-detection

I am seeking to run a common Java program in both Windows and Linux.

The program needs to do some things differently on each platform.

So how can / should my Java program detect it is running under Linux vs. Windows?

Comment: *"The program needs to do some things differently on each platform."*  What, specifically?

Answer (score 214):

[apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has a class [SystemUtils.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/SystemUtils.java)
you can use :

```
SystemUtils.IS_OS_LINUX
SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS
```

Comment: Simply tests whether `os.name` property begins with `Windows`...

Comment: @GeorgeChakhidze This is exactly how software breaks on newer Windows versions...

Answer (score 98):

Try:

```
System.getProperty("os.name");
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29

Comment: See also [`os.arch` & `os.version`](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=os.arch%2Cos.name%2Cos.version&format=TSV) (in case that matters).

Answer (score 67):

you can use this Useful simple [class](https://gist.github.com/AMDG2/9c657ed4efe102313831):

```
public class OSValidator {
 
    private static String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        System.out.println(OS);
 
        if (isWindows()) {
            System.out.println("This is Windows");
        } else if (isMac()) {
            System.out.println("This is MacOS");
        } else if (isUnix()) {
            System.out.println("This is Unix or Linux");
        } else if (isSolaris()) {
            System.out.println("This is Solaris");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your OS is not supported!!");
        }
    }
 
    public static boolean isWindows() {
        return OS.contains("win");
    }
 
    public static boolean isMac() {
        return OS.contains("mac");
    }
 
    public static boolean isUnix() {
        return (OS.contains("nix") || OS.contains("nux") || OS.contains("aix"));
    }
 
    public static boolean isSolaris() {
        return OS.contains("sunos");
    }

    public static String getOS(){
        if (isWindows()) {
            return "win";
        } else if (isMac()) {
            return "osx";
        } else if (isUnix()) {
            return "uni";
        } else if (isSolaris()) {
            return "sol";
        } else {
            return "err";
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `OS.indexOf("...")  >= 0` can be replaced with `OS.contains("...")`

Comment: Should probably use:  System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);

Answer (score 31):

I think It's a best approach to use Apache lang dependency to decide which OS you're running programmatically through Java

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_7)
            System.out.println("It's a Windows 7 OS");
        if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_8)
            System.out.println("It's a Windows 8 OS");
        if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_LINUX)
            System.out.println("It's a Linux OS");
        if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC)
            System.out.println("It's a MAC OS");
    }
}
```

Comment: if(File.separatorChar == '\\') windows = true;

Comment: Or just `SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use "system.properties.os", for example:

```
public class GetOs {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    String s = 
      "name: " + System.getProperty ("os.name");
    s += ", version: " + System.getProperty ("os.version");
    s += ", arch: " + System.getProperty ("os.arch");
    System.out.println ("OS=" + s);
  }
}

// EXAMPLE OUTPUT: OS=name: Windows 7, version: 6.1, arch: amd64
```

Here are more details:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html